# React router 3.x.x fires all onEnter's within <Router> at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have my routing set up in App.js that calls some Auth functions to check a JWT token's validation. All the code works, I get my users authenticated, however.. As soon as I hit the page, ALL of the onEnter functions seem to fire. Instead of just the route I'm actually visiting. Using react-router v3.x.x

The console.log now returns

> 'doing auth'

twice. If I add a new route and hookup the onEnter function, it fires three times. Remove one, fires once.

I'm completely at a loss where to start fixing this, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
class App extends Component {

    doAuth(authData) {
        console.log('doing auth');
    }

    render() {              
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route  
                        path="/" 
                        component={ AuthContainer } 
                />
                <Route 
                        path="/dashboard"    
                        component={ DashboardContainer }    
                        onEnter={this.doAuth({socket: this.socket, role: ['admin']})} 
                />
                <Route 
                        path="/digital-sign" 
                        component={ DigitalSignContainer }
                        onEnter={this.doAuth({socket: this.socket, role: ['admin', 'editor']})} 
                />
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router fires all `onEnter` because it's required to pass callbacks, not callback result values.

For example, in this way: `onEnter={() => this.doAuth({socket: this.socket, role: ['admin']})}`

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been trying to debug it in my auth script for ages. Again, thanks!